# Mail is sent successfully, but does not arrive

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I use the localhost (127.0.0.1) for sending mail in asp.net with C#. The code runs successfully. The message is displayed that the mail is sent successfully. However, I do not receive any new mail. Could you please help me for that?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information that that to get a meaningful response. What SMTP server are you using, what do the logs for your SMTP server say. Do you have a code extract. Are you SURE the email sent ok.

Comment: i use localhost for sending the mail!! its correct or wrong?

Comment: Unless you have set up a smtp server manually to handle localhost, using localhost is probably wrong.

Comment: oh okay then how to get the server name from the local system? can you please give the guidance for that

Comment: @sribharanidharan: Don't get it from the local system: make it part of the configuration for your web application.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing any code, it's hard to say exactly what's going on. There are two obvious possibilities:

- Your code to send the mail could be broken, failing to notice errors
- Your server may not be configured properly to send mail

It's probably worth trying the second idea first. If you use a standalone mail client (e.g. Thunderbird) and set the SMTP server to your ASP.NET server, can you send mail to yourself that way? Have you deliberately set up the server to work properly as an SMTP server?

Comment: @sribharanidharan: That's clearly not your actual code, as the case is all wrong. If you're not cut and pasting the actual code, you may have missed out the error. Also I would suggest you edit your question instead of posting large amounts of code in a comment. I don't know anything about Outlook Explorer, but look in the account settings - it shouldn't be too hard to find the SMTP server setting.

Comment: okay thank you!! i just typed the coding for your view thats why its seems like this!! now i'm in TCS i'm doing proj for them! any way thanx jon